# User Authentication and Authorization with grizzly websockets

Tags: websocket, glassfish-3, jaas, grizzly, j-security-check

I have gone through many tutorials on user authentication and authorization, most of them uses form based authentication(j_security_check) and @RolesAllowed for authorization and jdbcRealm.

So, if the authorization has to work I have to send an HTTP request from client to server. But what I want is send normal websocket request and if I am unauthorized to access the method (based on @RolesAllowed parameters) I should get an Exception.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please someone give some ideas. I need it badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Basic Auth. Encode with Base64 your username:password and send it in the request header's Authorization field. Then on the server decode and authenticate for every request. If resource should be available without authentication, use `@PermitAll`. Otherwise use `@RolesAllowed({"role1","role2"})`.

You can get the field from the request header like so:

```
request.getHeaderValue("Authorization");
```